# How do I toggle field required attribute after ng-click?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-change

I have a dropdown list in a repeater that should toggle my custom "required" attribute. I tried ng-show but the display="none" attribute is all that was added. My options are:-

**1-** Add/remove the input field and set bird.Stuff, not just hide it because it is still required.

**2-** Add/remove 'required' attribute on the input field.

**js**

```
$scope.validateParticipants = function (type) {
    if (type == "Single") {
        this.donation.Participants = "1";
    }
    else
        this.donation.Participants = "";
}
```

**html**

```
 <div ng-repeat="bird in animalTest.birds">
    @(Html.DropDownList("Type", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.BirdList, new { ng_model = "bird.Type", ng_change = "validateRequired(bird.Type)", required = "Type is required" }))
    ...
    <input data-ng-show="bird.Type == 'Endangered'" id="stuff" type="number" data-ng-model="bird.Stuff" required = "Number of Volunteers required"/>  
</div>
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [ng-required](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ainput). This takes an angular expression and adds the *required* attribute if the expression is true.

```
<input type="number" data-ng-model="bird.Stuff" ng-required="donation.Participants > 0"/>
```

Comment: Hi @GruffBunny, I have a situation when ng-required adds required attribute and doesn't remove it after ng-required value changed. Do you have any minds

Comment: Without seeing any code it's not easy to diagnose the problem. My gut feel is that the change is made but angular doesn't know about it (check out angular $apply). You're best way of getting an answer is to ask a new question and include code showing the problem.

Comment: thanks, for the answer. The mistake was in my code (I wrote ng-required="{{!user.id}}" - the problem was in braces)